# How can i find particular profile by id

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a slicer --

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    id:null,
    email:null,
    profiles:[],
    currentProfile:[],
}

export const userClise = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state,action) => {
      state.id = action.payload.id;
      state.email = action.payload.email;
      state.profiles = action.payload.profiles;
    },
    removeUser: (state) => {
      state.id = null;
      state.email = null;
      state.profiles = null;
    },
    addProfile: (state,action) => { // SLICE TO ADD PROFILE TO profiles.Array
      state.profiles.push(action.payload)
    },
    setCurrentProfile: (state,action) => { // SLICE TO FIND AND SET PROFILE
      state.currentProfile.push(state.profiles.filter((profile) => profile.id === action.payload));
    }
  },
})

export const { setUser, removeUser, addProfileName, setCurrentProfile } = userClise.actions;

export default userClise.reducer;
```

My reducer setCurrentProfile doesn't work.He gave me empty array ---
[image]

Here is i use dispatch with id of profile, this is component of profiles item, on parent component i map them from  -- profiles:[].
Logic is -  First i add profile, then on click profile i want to set this profile to currentProfile:[],

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setCurrentProfile } from '../../../redux/userSlice';

export default function UserProfileItem({name,bgImg,redirect,id}) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSetProfile = () =>{
    dispatch(setCurrentProfile(id))
  }

  return (
  <Link to={`/${redirect}`}>
    <li onClick={handleSetProfile} className='w-[153px] h-[201px] sm:w-[140px] sm:h-[175px] cursor-pointer mr-7 group flex items-center flex-col'>
        <div className='rounded-md border-4 border-transparent bg-center bg-cover w-full h-full group-hover:buttonUserScreen' style={{ backgroundImage:`url(${bgImg ? bgImg : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Netflix-avatar.png"})`}}>
        </div>
        <span className='mt-3 group-hover:text-[#fff]'>{name || "user name"}</span>
    </li>
  </Link>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you want to find only one profile you should use ```state.profiles.find((profile) => profile.id === action.payload)```. The ```find```method will be a better choice than ```filter```that return an array.

Comment: It seems like you are doing dispatch perfectly but can you confirm are you getting the id that you are sending  through payload in reducers?

Comment: i made console.log(action.payload) and its gave me id of item

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Somehow find by "id" doesnt work, but it works if i use "name" istead.

Comment: this is not a solution two users may have the same name that's why you should use `id`